# Jasmine unit test for angularjs promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

```
 $scope.$watch('hb.bulkPromise', function (promise) {
    promise.then(function (resource) {
        return resource.test();
    }).then(function (data){
    })
 }
```

I have a structure in my angular directive with promise. 
How can we write test for the above promise.

Comment: The title says how to test directive, but all you ahve here is a watch with promise, please provide more code

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. Need test for this chunk promise code.

Comment: and what framework you are using for unit tests?

Comment: Hi, I am using jasmine for test.

Answer (score 0):

When unit testing Angular, ***all*** promises are triggered to complete when you call $scope.$digest(). The timing is then up to you. The basic steps go:

1. Prep your test variables and other structures
2. Call the code that sets up the promise.
3. Call $scope.$digest() to trigger the promise.
4. Test for your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [jasmine testing framework](http://jasmine.github.io/).

I believe you will need to mock promises similar to [what is done here](http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2012/12/28/mocking-promises-in-unit-tests/) about halfway down the page..